# Guidelines for using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

What are guidelines for using `std::unique_ptr`?

For sure one should not use it when pointer is shared among other objects, modules. But meybe there are some other guidelines?

- for pImpl
- for member pointer inside class
- for what else?

hope this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: `for member pointer inside class` - ownership determines that - and yes, it is a dupe.

Comment: I'd say: use it whenever you need an owning pointer but don't need shared ownership.

Comment: Related: [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: There are typical use cases on the reference page for [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: About pimpl: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Not sure I agree with Herb here.  I don't really see what `unique_ptr` buys you in this case.  Either way, you have to define a non-inline destructor.

Comment: I am going to close this, as being not so constructive... thanks for the comments!